# How can I make my front end app access my node server apis

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cross-domain, create-react-app

I have created a front end app by **creat-react-app**.
The command "**npm run start**" can create a webpack-dev-server and serve my
front end app for developing. Here is the problem comes:

1. My front end app must request some **api** from a **node server** I had created before.
2. By default create-react-app start a webpack-dev-server on **port 3000**
3. My node server was started on **port 3001**
4. Access port 3001 directly may cause cross-origin problems

How can I gracefully start my developing story from those problems !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve cross-origin problems in node server,

1. Using cors node module

First install cors module. `npm install cors`

and then use it inside your app

```
const Express       = require("express");
const BodyParser    = require("body-parser");
const Cors          = require("cors");

const app = Express();
app.use(Cors());

app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(BodyParser.json());

app.listen(3001, 'localhost', (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
    console.log("Server listen port 8083");
});
```

2. simply use following headers

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to deal with CORS with a NodeJS backend is to use ExpressJS middleware and the "cors" extension, as detailed in the ExpressJS documentation:

[ExpressJS CORS guide](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)

For testing purposes there are various browser extensions that implement CORS headers  in all your requests automatically (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods 
, Access-Control-Allow-Headers).
Using this extension makes all your request from the browser CORS enabled (NOT GOOD FOR PRODUCTION, JUST FOR TEST/DEV).

Note that the so called "simple requests", ones using only GET / HEAD / POST and the following content types: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, text/plain do not trigger a CORS preflight request so they are allowed.

For a general understanding of CORS i would refer to the Mozilla MDN docs:

[Mozilla MDN CORS guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to overcome CORS issues is to use npm module for cors.
Install it in your project using:

```
npm i cors
```

Then include it in your app.js file like this:

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

and then use it as a middleware in your app.js like this:

```
app.use(cors());
```

And this should do!
Hope this helps!!